# Incomplete beta function in raw C

Tags: c, function, math, statistics, implementation

A friend of mine needs an analogue of MatLAB's `betainc` function for some statistical calculations in programmable logic devices (PLD's) (I'm not a man of hardware and don't know any details on his project yet).

Therefore using precompiled libraries is not an option. 
She needs an implementation in raw C considering that each of the three parameters is variable.

Is there a good one somewhere on the Web?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Look at the implementation in C++/TR1's `math.h` and copy that if necessary. It should be fairly easy to port to C.

Comment: Or you can copy the algorithm from `betainc.m` from the matlab source. Not so easy, but much more instructive.

Comment: This is a tricky function to implement well, depending on the parameters. If you know something about the range of the parameters on the beta distribution that you'll need to support, you can cut out a lot of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I'm late to answering, but your currently accepted answer (using code from "Numerical Recipes") has a terrible license. Also, it doesn't help others that don't already own the book.

Here is raw C99 code for the incomplete beta function released under the Zlib license:

```
#include <math.h>

#define STOP 1.0e-8
#define TINY 1.0e-30

double incbeta(double a, double b, double x) {
    if (x < 0.0 || x > 1.0) return 1.0/0.0;

    /*The continued fraction converges nicely for x < (a+1)/(a+b+2)*/
    if (x > (a+1.0)/(a+b+2.0)) {
        return (1.0-incbeta(b,a,1.0-x)); /*Use the fact that beta is symmetrical.*/
    }

    /*Find the first part before the continued fraction.*/
    const double lbeta_ab = lgamma(a)+lgamma(b)-lgamma(a+b);
    const double front = exp(log(x)*a+log(1.0-x)*b-lbeta_ab) / a;

    /*Use Lentz's algorithm to evaluate the continued fraction.*/
    double f = 1.0, c = 1.0, d = 0.0;

    int i, m;
    for (i = 0; i <= 200; ++i) {
        m = i/2;

        double numerator;
        if (i == 0) {
            numerator = 1.0; /*First numerator is 1.0.*/
        } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
            numerator = (m*(b-m)*x)/((a+2.0*m-1.0)*(a+2.0*m)); /*Even term.*/
        } else {
            numerator = -((a+m)*(a+b+m)*x)/((a+2.0*m)*(a+2.0*m+1)); /*Odd term.*/
        }

        /*Do an iteration of Lentz's algorithm.*/
        d = 1.0 + numerator * d;
        if (fabs(d) < TINY) d = TINY;
        d = 1.0 / d;

        c = 1.0 + numerator / c;
        if (fabs(c) < TINY) c = TINY;

        const double cd = c*d;
        f *= cd;

        /*Check for stop.*/
        if (fabs(1.0-cd) < STOP) {
            return front * (f-1.0);
        }
    }

    return 1.0/0.0; /*Needed more loops, did not converge.*/
}
```

It is taken from this [Github repo](https://github.com/codeplea/incbeta). There is also a very thorough write-up about [how it works here](https://codeplea.com/incomplete-beta-function-c).

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Agreed about the terrible license.  Great book, bad lawyers.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could read "Numerical Recipes in C" and find complete source.  You'll have to worry about licensing issues, but it'll have a lucid explanation of what the function and its implementation are about.